# how to load a image into a div, which image is loaded from database into another div

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of image in a div. which come from database query. I want one image from this div should display into another div after first div is loaded with images.

code:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code to show the problem in detail.

Comment: can you show us changeImage function?

Comment: SO users may sometimes want to copy-paste your code to kick the tires and provide a good hint/answer. Please dont use images to show code ... edit the code in the body of the question. See **[the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)** to learn how to edit your code in.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I am new in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Although question is not clear still      
  <?php
    // for php
    $dataSet = array();
    while($show = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $dataSet[] = $show;
    }
    ?>
    <div><?php echo $dataSet[0]['photo']; ?></div>
    ....
    <?php
    foreach($dataSet as $data) {
    ?>
        <div><?php echo $data['photo']; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $data['name']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
```